# Access secondary EBS volume and change permission of /.ssh directory - AWS

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have attached an EBS Volume(Centos based) with a new EC2 instance(Amazon Linux) as a secondary volume. The purpose of attaching it as a secondary volume is- I want to fix permission of /.ssh directory which has broken on previous ec2 instance because of that I was not able to ssh in to it, Putty was throwing "Server refused our key" and asking for password.

Now I don't know how to change permission of ./ssh directory of secondary volume, saw many posts over stackoverflow but didn't find the solution.

Current permission of ./ssh folder of secondary volume is 777.

Please suggest, How Can I change the permission on secondary volume?

Comment: I guess you could use ISO file on your VM to boot and modify your permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: If you have attached EBS to EC2 instance then to access it first you have to mount it and then you can change the permission using chmod command.

I followed below steps:

1. Created a new directory using following command.

> mkdir /mnt/xvdf1

2. Mounted secondary volume to /mnt/xvdf1 using following command.

> mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/xvdf1

3. Changed the permission of centos and /.ssh directory using following command.

> chmod 700 -R /mnt/home/centos
>   chmod 700 -R /mnt/home/centos/.ssh

4. Done