# Server refused our key - AWS

Tags: permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am getting following error since last few days.

> ```
>    Using username "centos".
>    Server refused our key
>    centos@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
> ```

It appeared after I changed permission of /home/centos since I wanted to view some files inside home/centos/.local folder.

**Current permissions are :**

/home/centos -> 755

/home/centos -> 777

/home/centos/.ssh -> 777

I visited this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-server-refused-our-key/), it says that -

> The procedure doesn't correct the issue if permissions to the home
>   directory are broken. You must manually correct the home directory
>   permissions

So I want to know **How can I fix these permissions manually?**

I am not able to change permissions using FileZilla and I am not able to login over instance using Putty.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new linux learner and I learned a lot after this issue came.

Since permissions of /centos and /.ssh directory was broken so I had to fix those.
Permission of /centos & /.ssh directory should be 700.

I followed below link to change the permission manually.

[Access secondary EBS volume and change permission of /.ssh directory - AWS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110821/access-secondary-ebs-volume-and-change-permission-of-ssh-directory-aws/1111899#1111899)

Detached the Volume and attached it back to the original instance.
Installed firewalld, enabled port 80 & 443, started Apache.

Now website is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was related to **.ssh**

If this directory containing your personal key, is read AND writeable to anyone else then the user, the system sees this as a security breach and ssh stops working.

Always make sure that,
**the folder has chmod 700**

Always make sure that your personal *.key is only readable by the user.

Here this is what it should look like

The folder has a chmod 700, the private key id_rsa a 600, public key and known_hosts has a 644

```
drwx------   5 s1mmel  staff   160B Dec 11 15:24 .
drwx------+ 46 s1mmel  staff   1.4K Jan 22 11:53 ..
-rw-------   1 s1mmel  staff   3.3K Dec 11 15:15 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 s1mmel  staff   745B Dec 11 15:15 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 s1mmel  staff   889B Jan 16 18:20 known_hosts
```